# Delphi SAPI 5.4 Freezes form when played

Tags: delphi, sapi

I have successfully installed SAPI 5.4 Microsoft text to speech in Delphi & works just fine when playing yet the hole application freezes.

Iv tried researching this problem but have not come across and solution & could not find anything help full on the the component it's self.

```
//Delphi Code
procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
Form1.SpVoice1.Speak('Hello World',0);
end;
```

Id Like this to work without freezing the hole application.

Comment: Because it still plays yet sorry i should reword.

Comment: The second parameter of 0 (SVSFDefault) to `Speak()` says to wait until it is done speaking to return.  Ref: [SpeechVoiceSpeakFlags (SAPI 5.3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms720892(v=vs.85))  If you want more information on using SAPI in Delphi a good place to start is to read the EDN article: [Speech Synthesis & Speech Recognition Using SAPI 5.1](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/29583)

Comment: "could not find anything help full on the the component it's self." That's because *you* created that component when importing it. It could potentially have a different name than other people using the same library. You should be searching not just Delphi or the component name, but the library you imported.

Comment: Good point @JerryDodge.

Comment: @Brian Thanks helped me alot.

Comment: I've rolled back your edit. It's not appropriate to add RESOLVED or SOLVED to the title, or edit a solution into your question. If you found a solution you'd like to share, write an  answer below in the space provided for that purpose.

Comment: i just made the parameter async

Comment: @KenWhite I believe the poster needs 15 reputation to answer their own question which they currently do not have (ref: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: @Brian: No, the 15 rep is only if you intend to both ask and answer immediately (an intentional self-answer, where you post a question followed immediately by the answer). There was at least a full hour between the time it was posted and when Jerry posted his comment that (seemingly) steered the poster toward a solution. But the rep requirement would not mean that the poster can add the solution to the question itself anyway, nor would it make adding RESOLVED or SOLVED to the title acceptable.

Comment: To clarify: The 15 rep requirement will allow the checkbox to display that you can use to indicate you're posting both a question and answer, and will enable writing both the question and answer on the same page and submit them both at the same time. You can at any time (and without a rep requirement) post a question and then return to post an answer to that question as a separate action. The 15 rep requirement to enable the checkbox is to prevent abuse of being able to do both by spammers.